# Cython 0.2: prange slowing down code unexpectedly

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, parallel-processing, cython

Consider optimized cython code in two cases:

```
    for j in xrange(8):
        for x in xrange(1, 600):
            tmp[j] = 0.0
            for y in xrange(1, 800):
                tmp[j] += mag[j, x - 1, y - 1]
                hgi_out[j, x, y] = tmp[j] + hgi_out[j, x - 1, y]
```

and:

```
    for j in prange(8):  # < prange used for parallelization with openmp
        for x in xrange(1, 600):
            tmp[j] = 0.0
            for y in xrange(1, 800):
                tmp[j] += mag[j, x - 1, y - 1]
                hgi_out[j, x, y] = tmp[j] + hgi_out[j, x - 1, y]
```

In both cases, the code is within a native function with **nogil** declared and numpy arrays with memory views and optimized layout. The benchamrked runtimes for the first case is **14.97** msecs while for the second its **26.64** aproximately doubling!!

I have other functions where the use of **prange** greatly improves performance on my multi-core machine except for the above cases, I don't understand what is happening.

Any ideas about why **prange** is slowing down the code?

FWIW, here's the complete original code:

```
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False
# cython: nonecheck=False
# cython: overflowcheck.fold=True
# cython: embedsignature=False
# cython: cdivision=True
# cython: cdivision_warnings=False
# cython: always_allow_keywords=False
# cython: profile=False
# cython: linetrace=False
# cython: infer_types=False
# cython: language_level=2
# cython: c_string_type=unicode
# cython: c_string_encoding=utf-8
# cython: type_version_tag=True
# cython: unraisable_tracebacks=True
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange

DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
UITYPE = np.uint
ctypedef np.uint_t UITYPE_t
U8TYPE = np.uint8
ctypedef np.uint8_t U8TYPE_t 
F32TYPE = np.float32
ctypedef np.float32_t F32TYPE_t
F64TYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t F64TYPE_t
ctypedef Py_ssize_t DSIZE_t

cdef void native_hog_integral_b(F64TYPE_t [:, :, ::1] mag,
                                F64TYPE_t [:, :, ::1] hgi_out) nogil:
    cdef DSIZE_t m, n, x, y, j, dims = mag.shape[0]
    cdef F64TYPE_t [32] tmp
    cdef F64TYPE_t val = 0
    m, n = mag.shape[1] + 1, mag.shape[2] + 1
    for j in prange(dims):
        for x in xrange(1, m):
            tmp[j] = 0.0
            for y in xrange(1, n):
                tmp[j] += mag[j, x - 1, y - 1]
                hgi_out[j, x, y] = tmp[j] + hgi_out[j, x - 1, y]

def hog_integral_b(mag, hgi_out=None, orientations=8):
    if hgi_out is None:
        hgi_out = np.zeros((orientations + 1, mag.shape[0] + 1, mag.shape[1] + 1), dtype=F64TYPE)
    native_hog_integral_b(mag, hgi_out)
    return hgi_out
```

To test the above code, try:

```
mg2 = np.random.rand(9, 600, 800).astype(F64TYPE)
hg2 = np.zeros((9, mg2.shape[1] + 1, mg2.shape[2] + 1), dtype=F64TYPE)
print timeit(lambda:hog_integral_b(mg2, hgi_out=hg2), number=10)
```

**UPDATE**:

Alright, I looked closely at my setup.py compiler options:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

ext_modules = [Extension("hog_cy", ["hog_cy.pyx"],
                         #extra_compile_args = ["-O3", "-fopenmp", "-fno-strict-aliasing"],
                         extra_compile_args = ["-O3", "-fopenmp"],
                         extra_link_args=["-fopenmp"]
                        )]

setup (
    name = 'performance test app',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
)
```

the option `-fno-strict-aliasing` seems to be making the problem, once switched off, I get no speedup but no loss as well.

Comment: Can you post a complete example?

Comment: I hope the question becomes clearer posting the whole code.

Comment: Sorry to be so pedantic but can you add a function to call `hog_integral_b` with sample (random) data of the right shape and dtype?

Comment: OK I will do this, give me some time

Comment: alright, answer update with test code at the end

Comment: @user698585 on my computer using your code `prange` is faster than with `range`

Comment: @Castro: you're kidding me!! I will double check the code in a separate package, it might be something with the compiler options, speaking of which, what did you use?

Comment: On mine the times are the same

Comment: @Castro, Mr E: I'm on a windows7 64 bit machine using mingw and python2.7 32bits. I'm using "-O3" and "-fopenmp" compiler options, what are yours?

Comment: @Mr E: maybe you don't have openmp properly configured, make sure you get some speedups on other benchmarks

Comment: @user698585 Out of curiosity, what is OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable set to?

Comment: @JoshAdel: its set to 2, check my update

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cython-users - You may try this for a better/complete answer: the cython team respond promptly

Answer (score 3):

You are producing a GIL battle because prange is not inside a nogil block. There is no concurrency in your code, only multiple threads competing for GIL ownership:

```
cimport cython
from cython.parallel cimport prange, parallel

cdef void native_hog_integral_b(F64TYPE_t [:, :, ::1] mag, 
                                F64TYPE_t [:, :, ::1] hgi_out):

    cdef DSIZE_t m, n, j, dims = mag.shape[0]
    cdef F64TYPE_t val = 0
    m, n = mag.shape[1] + 1, mag.shape[2] + 1
    with nogil, parallel():
        cdef DSIZE_t x, y
        cdef F64TYPE_t tmp
        for j in prange(dims):
            for x in range(1, m):
                tmp = 0.0
                for y in range(1, n):
                    tmp += mag[j, x - 1, y - 1]
                    hgi_out[j, x, y] = tmp + hgi_out[j, x - 1, y]
```

Comment: The native function (native_hog_integral_b) is declared with a nogil at the end its signature, this same pattern of declaration is working perfectly for other functions (not shown in the code above). I was thinking maybe the compiler is not considering some of the internal variable as local thread-safe (ex: tmp) but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: A nogil declaration of a function does not require the GIL to be released, nor does it release the GIL, it allows the use of the function inside a nogil block. You can use nogil functions while holding the GIL. The GIL is not released until you type "with nogil:"

Answer (score 0):

```
cimport cython
from cython.parallel cimport prange, parallel

cdef void native_hog_integral_b(F64TYPE_t [:, :, ::1] mag, 
                                F64TYPE_t [:, :, ::1] hgi_out):

    cdef DSIZE_t m, n, j, dims = mag.shape[0]
    cdef F64TYPE_t val = 0
    m, n = mag.shape[1] + 1, mag.shape[2] + 1
    with nogil, parallel():
        cdef DSIZE_t x, y
        cdef F64TYPE_t tmp
        for j in prange(dims):
            for x in range(1, m):
                tmp = 0.0
                for y in range(1, n):
                    tmp += mag[j, x - 1, y - 1]
                    hgi_out[j, x, y] = tmp + hgi_out[j, x - 1, y]
```